# What's the fastest way to kill an ogre by myself?

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

I've set up my diabolical traps.  They've killed 99% of the enemies coming through the gate, but I've been distracted on the other side of the map and don't notice the ogre that smashed through my hallway of death until he's almost to the rift.

What's the fastest (non-trap) way to kill the thing?  I like the crossbow with headshots giving back mana, and stun locking him with alternate fire, but when there are two I quickly lose.

Comment: *"when there are two I quickly lose"* - The sorceress's staff's incredibly OP secondary fire can take out literally any number of ogres:  take over one, and attack the others while they attack the one you've taken over.  By the time they kill it *(or you stop taking it over)*, you'll have enough mana to take over another one, ad infinitum.  However, that's probably not the **fastest** way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A combination of the crossbow with the upgrade that grants mana on a headshot, and the frost bracelet (seriously a very powerful tool, I never slay orcs without it) will allow you to stunlock multiple ogres indefinitely, while also holding them perfectly still allowing for easy headshots (as opposed the the crossbow's secondary fire where they sway their heads).

In combination with a fully upgraded crossbow, you can hold an ogre perfectly still and take it down in 3-5 headshots, normally before the frozen state is even broken, and if it does break, you can just freeze them again.

This works even better if you use the secondary fire and have upgraded the bracelet to make enemies frozen by your secondary fire take more damage. Not only will it freeze many many orcs and ogres, but it lasts much longer (I think it's over 5 seconds) and they will take more damage as well.

The only problem with this strategy is frost ogres, who are immune to the bracelet. In this case, you're just going to have to stunlock it with your crossbow's secondary fire, and aim at the moving head.

There is no other weapon that kills as quickly as multiple headshots from the crossbow.

Comment: You can kill a frost ogre with just a few hits from a flame bracelet - they take extra damage from it

Comment: I like to use the lightning bracelet, whose secondary fire can slow the orgre and deal considerable damage. Enough to finish them with headshots.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the kill-box, character and level.

On levels with heavy Ogres as the Warmage I like to use the Blunderbuss with 'sometimes knocks back' and the lightning ring with 'chills enemies'  As the heavy enemies start to break past your defenses seduce them back to the center of your kill-box with decoys or by standing in the thick of it whilst dumping mana.

It is a versatile combination for nightmare, skulling or endless runs because it can deal the trio of physical damage, slowing power and combo-kill to every orc, flier, heavy, kobol and sapper in the game with only three slots.

Charm as a sorceress is good, however you will end up damaging your barricades and it is less effective against the heaviest enemies.  The crossbow is great for adding combo's and stunning power however it is a very slow tactic against heavies.  As you are stun-locking the one heavy and vainly trying to get a head shot at close range there will be other Orcs that require attention... There are always more Orc.

Comment: Did I miss something? You say the blunderbuss and the lightning ring, but then say it takes three slots? Is there another item involved?

Comment: @Kexlox - the third being the decoy

Answer (score -1):

The best way to slay heavies, in my opinion, is to shoot them with the blunderbuss with knock back, then follow up by meleeing them with the dwarven hammer with stun. If you use frost bracelet, you can instagib them with the berserk amulet.

Comment: You need to clean this up to be more legible.  Also, the question is asking the *fastest* way to kill an ogre, not *best*.  Please re-read the question to ensure you know the difference.